# How to persist data in ESP8266 using Preferences.h

Tags: esp8266, arduino-c++

After many hours (days!) I noticed that almost only examples coming with the `Preferences.h` library are used, but nothing of those actually matches my needs.
As I am a complete C NOOB I'm stuck in types, casting and everything horrific that comes with it :-(

So: I am writing code for a battery-driven ESP8266 that reads a sensor and publishes it on an MQTT bus. I want to get rid of hard-coded credentials. The WiFiManager.h library by default supports changing WiFi credentials using a 'ConfigPortal' webinterface. There, I want to add custom fields for MQTT that can be changed and saved to persistant memory as well.

This is the global idea:

```
#include <Preferences.h>

// Declare vars 
char mqtt_server[40];
char mqtt_port[6];
char mqtt_user[20];
char mqtt_pass[20];

// Read data from persistant memory or else return default
mqtt_server = preferences.getChar("mqtt_server", "default mqtt server");
mqtt_port = preferences.getChar("mqtt_port", "default mqtt port");
mqtt_user = preferences.getChar("mqtt_user", "default mqtt user");
mqtt_pass = preferences.getChar("mqtt_pass", "default mqtt pass");

// Connect to mqtt broker using the vars as just defined

// Pushing a button starts a ConfigPortal webinterface to change these vars
// Write new data to persistant memory
// get the new data from the webform (called "Mqtt_server.
preferences.begin("mqtt_config", false);
preferences.putChar("mqtt_server", new_mqtt_server);
preferences.putChar("mqtt_port", new_mqtt_port);
preferences.putChar("mqtt_user", new_mqtt_user);
preferences.putChar("mqtt_pass", new_mqtt_pass);
preferences.end();
```

Consider this as pseudo-code which shows what I want to achieve.

I have questions like:

- How can I get data into the 'mqtt_server'? ( currently only get the first character)
- Why does getChar only allow an integer as default return value where I expect a default text to be possible? (the example shows the default text but accepts only eg. '0'.

Currently I am lost so this is my last resort... Thank you in advance for thinking along!

Comment: The name `getChar` and `putChar` should be a hint. Doesn't there exists something like `getString`, or `getChars` (note plural `s`)? Also remember that you can't assign to arrays, only copy to them. And also remember that strings in C (and C++ which you're really programming in) are really called ***null-terminated** strings*.

Comment: where did you get the Preferences library? esp32 has it bundled, but esp8266 Arduino doesn't. I can't just guess the usage

Comment: @Juraj - I use the Arduino IDE with an ESP8266 (ESP-12 actually board) and there I had to install it separately

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - yes - ```getString``` exists. So I should use the ```putString``` / ```getString``` and then copy it to the ```Char``` array?

Comment: This seems to work:
`
  Serial.print("mqtt_server ->>>> : ");
  Serial.println(preferences.getString("mqtt_server"));
  String tmp = preferences.getString("mqtt_server");
  strncpy(mqtt_server, tmp.c_str(), sizeof mqtt_server -1);
  
  preferences.putString("mqtt_server", "mqtt_server test");
` (formatting is not working - sorry)

Comment: If you install the library, why don't you take a look at the examples from the library on how to use it? BTW, Arduino is Arduino-C++, not C, so don't tag C.

Comment: Because I read the library documentation over and over again and still had troubles understanding it. As said: Almost every example on the internet is not more than a copy of the original example, only using 'int'. I am really in a steep learning curve currently. I see the tags are changed to fit this question better - great. All in all I have a working situation which is great and I already learned lots. Thanks all!